# Delete all items from a very extensive SharePoint Online list with many formulas

Tags: sharepoint

I would like to delete all the items (including the ID, which I want it to start from 1 again) in a Sharepoint list with many columns and many formulas on them. I have tried to create one new blank with "CREATE A LIST FROM AN EXISTING LIST" but that did not work because my formulas were not copied.

Any ideas so that I do not have to recreate the list column by column? It would take me such a long time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature that allows you to duplicate a list with a different name.
After deleting the new list you can create the same list with its original name.

You can find this when you try to create a list from "site contents". 
Just select the site and list.

Only works in SharePoint online

It copies formulae and lookups too. This is a very useful feature.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but that did not work to me because I tried but it copies me only the columns that do not have any formulas or lookups in them, and in my case the majority of them have. Any other idea, please? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes, I read about that, but I do not have that functionality in my SP and I don't know why.